# Include post id[s] into WP_Query()

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, pre-get-posts

I'm assigning some posts to some users whom are not the author of those posts. Typically private posts are visible only to the post authors. So, if the author has 3 posts, on his logged in `edit.php` they will get 3 posts. But if another post is assigned to them by custom field (not as a post author), how can I add the post to the post list table?

What I tried so far is: making a function (`custom_get_assigned_posts()`) to retrieve all the posts that are assigned to a user_id as an array. But then found that there's no easy way including post IDs into the existing query:

```
function add_assigned_posts( $query ) {
    if( is_admin() && in_array( $query->get('post_type'), array('mycpt') ) ) {
        global $current_user;
        $query->set('post__in', custom_get_assigned_posts( $current_user->ID ) );
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_assigned_posts' );
```

But `post__in` doesn't additionally include things, it actually specified posts to retrieve.

How can I include posts that are assigned to a non-author of posts, and are assigned by postmeta?

Comment: This is a good question. I'm wondering whether though rather than modifying the admin queries, looking to add capabilities to the user might work? I'm not entirely sure, just a suggestion

Comment: Adding capabilities provide access to all the posts, not to specific posts only. I tried that.

Comment: You should add that when you say 'What I tried so far' :)

Comment: Coming back to this, I think you can do this with capabilities - by filtering them to change them on a per post basis. I've just added an answer, let me know if this solves it for you.

Comment: I'd recommend updating the title of your question too - it doesn't explain what you want to do and will make it harder for people to find and help :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should be able to do this with the [`user_has_cap` filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/user_has_cap).

Because that filter passes through the post ID in the `$args` for the `edit_post` capability, you can use that to check if the current user has been artificially given this capability - and if so, force the `edit_post` capability to be true for that instance.

Building from the example in the docs linked above, you'd be looking at something like this:

```
add_filter( 'user_has_cap', 'wpse_227418_edit_extra_posts', 10, 3 );

function wpse_227418_edit_extra_posts($allcaps, $cap, $args){

  if($args[0] != "edit_post"){
    return $allcaps; // bail out, we're not talking about editing a post here
  }

  if(get_post_meta($args[2], "additional_author", true) == $args[1]){
    // get the meta key 'additional author', checking that it matches the User ID we're looking at the capabilities for
    $allcaps[$cap[0]] = true; // make sure edit_posts is true for this author and this post ID
  }

  return $allcaps;

}
```

This is pretty quickly put together and is untested so you'd certainly want to test and modify to your needs, but I think this will get you what you want. Of course, adjust the meta_key referred to above to match the key you're after.

References:

- [user_has_cap filter on Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/user_has_cap)
- [has_cap() function in WP_User class](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.2/src/wp-includes/class-wp-user.php#L692) (the function that calls the above filter)

Comment: Tim, nice shot. This filter is really useful. Upvote for that. But I forgot to mention that (probably I forgot many thing :( and disappointed you), I'm using `private` status for all my posts. But `user_has_cap` filter works for published and pending. So the post list is already populated with only private posts to that user, I can't push the assigned posts to them. :(

Comment: No, you did mention that - I forgot to take that into account when listing the posts, but thinking about it again perhaps WP is just checking a different capability when loading the posts list? Looking at [the capabilities list](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities), perhaps as well as checking for edit_post we also need to check for `edit_private_posts`, maybe also `read_private_posts`. Can you do a bit of debugging on that filter and see what is called on the posts page?

Comment: How did you go with this @MayeenulIslam?

Comment: I failed initially. Tried thrice, but failed. Then I [altered the query](https://github.com/nanodesigns/nanosupport/blob/master/includes/ns-set-environment.php#L589-L653), and granted access to assigned tickets. It may need another shot sometime, but currently not possible for me.